# Links not working in a Repeat Region in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I recently download this [Slideshow with jmpress.js](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/05/slideshow-with-jmpress-js/) for a website. I'm using PHP and a database in MYSQL. I used a recordset in Dreamweaver to get the data from database to the site. Then I tried to create a Repeat Region to show the latests posts in the slider.

Headings, images and text are working fine. The problem is on the href (links), which are not changed and remain the same (the ID of the latest post) for all records.

**In the head I have these files:**

- SlideshowJmpress/css/style.css
- http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
- SlideshowJmpress/js/jmpress.min.js
- SlideshowJmpress/js/jquery.jmslideshow.js
- SlideshowJmpress/js/modernizr.custom.48780.js

**Here is the HTML Code**:

```
<section id="jms-slideshow" class="jms-slideshow">
    <?php do { ?>
        <div class="step" data-color="color-1">
            <div class="jms-content">
                <h3><?php echo $row_slider['packageTitle']; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $row_slider['packageDescription']; ?></p>
                <a class="jms-link" href="article.php?ID=<?php echo $row_slider['ID']; ?>">Read more</a>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo $row_slider['packageGraphic']; ?>" width="300px;" height="300px;" />
        </div>              
    <?php } while ($row_slider = mysql_fetch_assoc($slider)); ?> 
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( '#jms-slideshow' ).jmslideshow({

        });
    });
</script>
```

**Here is the php code for the recordset:**

```
$maxRows_slider = 4;
$pageNum_slider = 0;
if (isset($_GET['pageNum_slider'])) {
  $pageNum_slider = $_GET['pageNum_slider'];
}
$startRow_slider = $pageNum_slider * $maxRows_slider;

mysql_select_db($database_nipvlach, $nipvlach);
$query_slider = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY `date` DESC";
$query_limit_slider = sprintf("%s LIMIT %d, %d", $query_slider, $startRow_slider, $maxRows_slider);
$slider = mysql_query($query_limit_slider, $nipvlach) or die(mysql_error());
$row_slider = mysql_fetch_assoc($slider);

if (isset($_GET['totalRows_slider'])) {
  $totalRows_slider = $_GET['totalRows_slider'];
} else {
  $all_slider = mysql_query($query_slider);
  $totalRows_slider = mysql_num_rows($all_slider);
}
$totalPages_slider = ceil($totalRows_slider/$maxRows_slider)-0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is either in IDs in your DB or in the slideshow script i think.

Look at source of your page. Are the links right ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the script or in the jmpress.min.js

When I changed slider, everything worked fine!